# Stop servicing requests from backend web servers configured in the load balancer

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy, distributed-system, system-design, horizontal-scaling

I have configured a load balancer using HAProxy on frontend and on the backend I have 4 server serving the request using Apache web server.

```
#HAProxy for web servers
frontend web-frontend
  bind IPADDRESS_LB:80
  mode http
  default_backend web-backend

backend web-backend
  balance roundrobin
  server web-server1 IPADDRESS1:80 check
  server web-server2 IPADDRESS2:80 check
  server web-server3 IPADDRESS3:80 check
  server web-server4 IPADDRESS4:80 check
```

Although my load balancer is working fine and my requests are served by either of the machines (IPADDRESS1-4) in a round robin mechanism.

But I see that my requests are being served by machines IPADDRESS1-4 individually as well. I want only my Load balancer to send requests to the backend server and not end user to directly make the requests.

How can I stop end user to access the webapp using any IP other than the Load Balancer IP?

Comment: You can write a firewall rule on the machines running apache server to allow the traffic only from the load balancer ip.

Comment: any source? example?